# Oracle - Join tables using aggregated function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table with "users" in it, and a table with "events" related to users, date-stamped as to when each event took place.   I'd like to produce a simple table showing each user and the **most recent event** that took place, but I can't quite work out the nested query or aggregation function to do this, since I'm not aggregating on the column I want.  If I simply wanted `MAX(event_date)` that would be fairly simple, but I want something like `event_status where MAX(event_date)`. I'm sure it's possible to do without resorting to a procedure, but I can't quite work it out.   Anyone got a solution?

```
    user_id   user_name 
    1           bob
    2           sally
    3           fred



    event_id   user_id  event_date  event_status
    1             1       3/1/15      hired
    2             1       3/2/15      active
    3             3       4/1/15      hired
    4             3       4/3/15      on leave
    5             2       3/3/15      hired
    6             2       4/1/15      on leave
    7             2       5/1/15      active
```

Desired result:

```
    user_name   current_status
    bob          active
    sally        active
    fred         on leave
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be simplest using a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select e.status
        from events e
        where e.user_id = u.user_id
        order by e.event_date desc
        limit 1
       ) as Most_Recent_Status
from users u;
```

This saves the trouble of aggregation (or equivalently `select distinct`) which is rather expensive in some databases.  Note that this uses the MySQL/Postgres `LIMIT 1` for the subquery.  Other databases have similar functionality.

EDIT:

```
select u.*,
       (select max(e.status) keep (dense_rank first order by event_date desc)
        from events e
        where e.user_id = u.user_id
       ) as Most_Recent_Status
from users u;
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me over the bump.   Oracle is slightly more awkward in its use of "limit" - I eventually got it to work by separating the ORDER BY from the ROWCOUNT=1 like so:

select u.*,
       (select * from 
           (select e.status
            from events e
            where e.user_id = u.user_id
            order by e.event_date desc        
           ) where rowcount=1) as Most_RecentStatus
from users u;

Answer (score 0):

the main idea is to select latest event for every user and then join tables:

```
select a.user_name, b.event_status
from
users as a
inner join
events as b
on (a.user_id = b.user_id)
inner join
(
    select user_id, max(event_id) as event_id
    from table2
    group by user_id
) as q
on (b.user_id = q.user_id and b.event_id = q.event_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sql query:

```
select U.user_name, 
       E.event_status 
  from users  U, 
       events E
 where U.user_id = E.user_id
   and (E.user_id, E.event_date) = (select distinct user_id, 
                                           max(event_date) 
                                      from events  
                                     where user_id = E.user_id group by user_id
                                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tested with SQL Server 2014, YMMV for other databases**

(Please change the names of the columns and tables appropriately.)

Short answer

```
SELECT 
username, eventstatus
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         u.username,
         e.eventstatus,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.username ORDER BY e.eventdate DESC) RowNum
    FROM @userTable u JOIN @eventTable e ON u.userid=e.userid
) sub
WHERE sub.RowNum = 1
```

Long test

```
DECLARE @userTable TABLE (userid INT, username VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @eventTable TABLE (eventid INT, userid INT, eventdate DATETIME, eventstatus VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @userTable VALUES (1, 'bob')
INSERT INTO @userTable VALUES (2, 'sally')
INSERT INTO @userTable VALUES (3, 'fred')

INSERT INTO @eventTable VALUES (1, 1, '3/1/15', 'hired')
INSERT INTO @eventTable VALUES (2, 1, '3/2/15', 'active')
INSERT INTO @eventTable VALUES (3, 3, '4/1/15', 'hired')
INSERT INTO @eventTable VALUES (4, 3, '4/3/15', 'on leave')
INSERT INTO @eventTable VALUES (5, 2, '3/3/15', 'hired')
INSERT INTO @eventTable VALUES (6, 2, '4/1/15', 'on leave')
INSERT INTO @eventTable VALUES (7, 2, '5/1/15', 'active')

SELECT 
username, eventstatus
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         u.username,
         e.eventstatus,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.username ORDER BY e.eventdate DESC) RowNum
    FROM @userTable u JOIN @eventTable e ON u.userid=e.userid
) sub
WHERE sub.RowNum = 1
```